# Storing values from data DataGrid Cells into array and get number or columns and rows?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I need to do some manipulation on the data extracted from it. I will not know the number of rows and columns in advance and it has to depend on the way you select the data using your mouse (Similar to how you will do it in a spreadsheet).

Here is the code I am using:

```
public double[] ExtractGridData(DataGridView grid)
    {
        int numCells = grid.SelectedCells.Count;
        double[] cellsData = new double[numCells];

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grid.SelectedCells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null)
                    cellsData[cell.RowIndex] = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
            }
        return cellsData;
    }
```

One problem is that, the way the values are stored depend on the direction of selection. Is there a way to make sure cell (0,0) is first value in array, cell (0,1) as the second and so on?

I want the final result to be in a two dimensional matrix, rows and columns. So I was planning on finding the number of columns and then making this array into a two dimensional one. So that, now I can find total of each row in the array or the cells in datagridview.

Comment: Do you mean data item in selected row ?

Comment: @matzone - The selection will be a few rows and columns. Like a rectangular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the results (or selected cells by position). For example:

```
public double[] ExtractGridData(DataGridView grid)
        {
            int numCells = grid.SelectedCells.Count;
            double[] cellsData = new double[numCells];
            int[] cellsKeys = new int[numCells];
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grid.SelectedCells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null)
                {
                    cellsData[cnt] = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
                    cellsKeys[cnt] = cell.RowIndex + cell.ColumnIndex * grid.ColumnCount;
                    cnt++;
                };

            }
            Array.Sort(cellsKeys, cellsData);
            return cellsData;
        }
```

You can modify the key creation process to achieve desired order. Are you really sure you do not need information about selection position?